# Rotulo dos dados em gráficos de colunas na posição "dodge" no R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico

Estou trabalhando com o seguinte data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)

df<- data.frame(Ano=c(2017, 2018,2019,2020), Vagas=c(16, 14, 27, 32), Inscritos=c(70, 107,74,88), Aprovados=c(15,14,17, 12))

df

 Ano Vagas Inscritos Aprovados
1 2017    16        70        15
2 2018    14       107        14
3 2019    27        74        17
4 2020    32        88        12
```

Preciso expressar isso na forma de um gráfico de colunas.
Então, converto para o formato tidy como "gather"

```
df2<-df %>% 
  gather(Condicao, n, c(Vagas:Aprovados))

Ano  Condicao   n
1  2017     Vagas  16
2  2018     Vagas  14
3  2019     Vagas  27
4  2020     Vagas  32
5  2017 Inscritos  70
6  2018 Inscritos 107
7  2019 Inscritos  74
8  2020 Inscritos  88
9  2017 Aprovados  15
10 2018 Aprovados  14
11 2019 Aprovados  17
12 2020 Aprovados  12
```

Eu gostaria de expressar os dados na forma de colunas lado a lado.
Então uso o `geom_col()` com a posição `dodge`

```
df2 %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_col(aes(Ano, n, fill=Condicao), position="dodge")
```

[image: grafico 1]

Consigo criar os labels usando o `geom_label()`:

```
df2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Ano, Condicao, label = n))+
  geom_label(aes(Ano, n, label=n))
```

[image: grafico 2]

No entanto, não consigo juntar ambos da forma correta.

Tentei:

```
df2 %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_col(aes(Ano, n, fill=Condicao), position="dodge")+
  geom_label(aes(Ano, n, label=n), position = "dodge")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha intenção é que os rótulos estejam ALINHADOS às suas respectivas colunas:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode resolver o problema com

1. Por `aes(Ano, n)` na chamada inicial a `ggplot`. Isto simplifica as `geom_*` seguintes uma vez que partilham os valores dos eixos.
2. Definir a variável de agrupamento das barras também logo no início. Fica então `aes(Ano, n, group = Condicao)`.
3. Usar `position_dodge(width = 1)` em `geom_label`.

O gráfico final é o seguinte.

```
df2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Ano, n, group = Condicao)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Condicao), position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_label(aes(label = n), position = position_dodge(width = 1))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Perfeito. Exatamente o que buscava. Obrigado Rui Barradas

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar `position = position_dodge(width = 1)`

Código:

```
df2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Ano, n, fill=Condicao))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position="dodge") +
  geom_label(aes(Ano, n, label= n), position = position_dodge(width = 1))
```